# VBA Passing an array to a function and back

Tags: arrays, vba, function

I've started to review cpearson's essay on passing and returning arrays, and I'm getting a bit lost in the details. The below doesn't work, and is confirmed by the essay. It seems like I might be able to correct the problem by looping through the arrays to set each element equal to the element in the other array. How do I do this with a function?

```
Sub test()

    Dim Arr() as Variant
    Dim CurrDoc as Word.Document

    ReDim Arr(0 to 39, 0 to 1)

    Arr() = FillArr(CurrDoc, Arr())

End Sub

Function FillArr(CurrentDocument As Word.Document, CurrentArray() As Variant) As Variant

    j = 1

    For Each chk In CurrentDocument.ContentControls

        If chk.Type = 8 Then

            CurrentArray(j, 1) = chk.Title
            CurrentArray(j, 2) = chk.Checked

            j = j + 1

        End If

    Next chk

FillArr() = CurrentArray()

End Function
```

Comment: Why are you `ReDim AnsArr(1 to 40, 1 to 2)` but then using `Arr`?

Comment: ^ and returning ```CurrentArr()``` which isn't used anywhere else.

Comment: `Option Explicit` FTW   Also `CurrDoc` is Nothing as you didn't set it.

Comment: ^ Except it wouldn't flag the `AnsArr` in `ReDim AnsArr`... but anyway, yes you need `Option Explicit` badly.

Comment: Arrays start counting at 0. Get used to it. :)

Comment: Fixed the typos. I copied half and typed the other half and made some errors--my apologies.

Imagine that I've set CurrDoc to a specific document. That part is fine.

Changed to 0 to 39 and 0 to 1 just for your Tomalak. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't feel like making a word doc to match yours exactly but you can pass arrays through functions. I'm going to populate mine with random characters.

```
Sub test()
    Dim arr() As Variant
    ReDim arr(1 To 40, 1 To 2)

    arr() = fillarr(arr())

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 40
        Debug.Print i, arr(i, 1)
        Debug.Print i & "* 5", arr(i, 2)
    Next i
End Sub

Function fillarr(currentarr() As Variant) As Variant
    Dim j As Long

    For j = 1 To 40
        currentarr(j, 1) = Chr(j + 64)
        currentarr(j, 2) = Chr(j * 5)
    Next j

    fillarr = currentarr
End Function
```

There's actually an implicit `by ref` because in VBA arrays are always passed by reference so you don't actually need a function to do this, though you probably should as it is clearer, but you can see this here:

```
Sub test()
    Dim arr() As Variant
    ReDim arr(1 To 40, 1 To 2)

    fillarr arr() 'no value set

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 40
        Debug.Print i, arr(i, 1)
        Debug.Print i & "* 5", arr(i, 2)
    Next i
End Sub

Sub fillarr(currentarr() As Variant)
    Dim j As Long

    For j = 1 To 40
        currentarr(j, 1) = Chr(j + 64)
        currentarr(j, 2) = Chr(j * 5)
    Next j

    'Note the lack of return
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like my error was in my return line: `FillArr = CurrentArr()` instead of `FillArr() = CurrentArr()`. Why is this?

Comment: because it thinks that's a function call and wants the parameter, really the ```CurrentArr()``` shouldn't have it either (I think, though I'm not positive, that after the declaration it is known to be an array and unless you need to redim or index it is not needed), that's my bad.

Comment: I know that I need it for CurrentArr() to ensure that when the array is declared that it's a Variant-type array of Variant-type elements. The function call bit makes perfect sense, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would approach this differently.

The usefulness of a function that returns titles and "checked" state of all "ceckbox" type content controls is lower than that of a function that just returns all content controls of a certain type. Here is why:

The code that calls the function already knows that it wants to use `Title` and `Checked`, so nothing is lost when it gets an array of `ContentControl` instances instead of a multi-dimensional array of strings and booleans. But when the calling code wants to manipulate the checkboxes, the "strings and booleans" approach falls short.

Under this assumption we can shed one dimension of the array, and get a function that can be re-used in different scenarios.

Also we don't need any array passing. Just build the array and return it:

```
Function FindControls(Doc As Word.Document, ControlType As WdContentControlType) As Variant
    Dim cct As Variant, i As Integer

    ' figure out how many matching controls there are and allocate an array
    For Each cct In Doc.ContentControls
        If cct.Type = ControlType Then i = i + 1
    Next cct
    ReDim cctArray(i - 1)

    ' save references to matching controls in array
    i = 0
    For Each cct In Doc.ContentControls
        If cct.Type = ControlType Then
            Set cctArray(i) = cct
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next cct

    FindControls = cctArray
End Function
```

Now we can use it quite naturally in the calling code:

```
Dim c As Variant

For Each c In FindControls(ActiveDocument, wdContentControlCheckbox)
    Debug.Print c.Title, c.Checked
Next
```

Comment: This... except, why not return a `Collection` and just `.Add` objects as we iterate `Doc.ContentControls` only once? Kudos for avoiding the in-loop `ReDim Preserve ...n+1` trap!

Comment: @Mathieu I don't know... I could have used a collection, I concluded it would not make enough of a difference to using an array. In this situation, they both handle about the same, from a calling-code perspective, and the functionality that allows dynamic adding and removing of items is not needed in the calling code either. So I chose the array.

Comment: Thanks. What are the relative merits of this solution as compared to Warcupine's below? Warcupine's method is much more intuitive to me.

Comment: @Michael The relative merits are in the 3rd paragraph. The other answer might be more intuitive to you because it looks more like your code on first glace. Try to really work out what my code does before you judge. *(For example - What's `40`? Why does your code need it and mine doesn't? Isn't it better to have code that does not need hard-coded numbers like this?)*

Comment: I should have phrased my question differently. I was asking, "if I am only interested in the current state of the checkboxes, and not in manipulating them at all, are there any benefits?" It looks like I'd see a small performance benefit by returning a smaller array. Your code is tremendously helpful in that you've helped me realize that I only need to write the ContentControl title to the array if `Checked = True.` Thank you.

Comment: @Michael If you are only interested in the checkbox state, then only use the checkbox state. I don't see any difference to a function that returns a boolean. You literally lose nothing (writing `result(2)` to get the "checked" state is just as complex as writing `result.Checked`, but the latter reads **a lot** easier) and you gain a ton of options should there ever be a time when you are doing more than reading out the "checked" state.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for your time and detailed replies.